# Apply Setter on XML Deserialize C#

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework-core

With the following EF Core entity class, I am unable to populate Orders by utilizing `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()`

OrderIds does serialize correctly, but the setter never gets called. I'm doing this to avoid a circular reference in the XML.

```cs
[Serializable]
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
    }
        
    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; }
    
    [NotMapped]
    [XmlArray("OrderIds")]
    [XmlArrayItem("OrderId")]
    public List<string> OrderIds
    {
        get => this.Orders
                .Select(o => o.OrderId).ToList();
        
        set // Never Called
        {
            this.Orders.Clear();
            foreach (var id in value)
            {
                var order = new Order()
                {
                    OrderId = id,
                };
                this.Orders.Add(order);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an XML Sample, generated with `XmlSerializer.Serialize()`:

```xml
<Report>
    <Customer>
        <Name>John Smith</Name>
        <Age>33</Age>
        <OrderIds>
            <OrderId>A</OrderId>
            <OrderId>B</OrderId>
        </OrderIds>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Name>Jane Doe</Name>
        <Age>33</Age>
        <OrderIds>
            <OrderId>C</OrderId>
            <OrderId>D</OrderId>
        </OrderIds>
    </Customer>
</Report>
```

Comment: Does xml file contain one or two tags (OrderIDs and OrderID)?   If there is only one than replace XmlArray and XmlArryItem with XmlElement.

Comment: Xml file contains multiple `OrderId` elements nested under a single `OrderIds` per `Customer` element. I can post a snippet of the schema and xml in the mornining (I'm in eastern time)

Comment: Need to see sample of XML.

Comment: @jdweng, added XML sample

Comment: Found this today, which answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281882/setter-not-called-when-deserializing-collection